# Django 3-table join orm

Tags: python, django

```py
class Address(models.Model):
    ...

class Ship(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='builtship')

class Photos(models.Model):
    ship = models.ForeignKey(Ship, related_name="photoship"
```

While I can easily join ship with the Address model, as it has its related name inside ship, I can't join it with Photos because it doesn't have it.

So, to join with Address I did:

`q1= ship.objects.select_related('address')`

but I tried for the entire Sunday and I couldn't write it ORM style. I wrote it in 2 minutes in raw SQL but I want to know how to link ship with photos too in one query so that I can fetch all the values and list them in a table.

Naturally, I can't place the foreign key to photos in the ship because every ship has many possible pictures, so it has to go from photos to ship.

I have already written what I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only join tables along foreign keys, but not backwards. The reason is that a Django join requires each of your objects in the main model to relate to no more then one object in the joined model.

Example:

You can join Ship with Photos, because every photo relates to exactly one ship. But not the other way around, because every ship relates potentially to many photos.

So you can either restructure your query to start from Photos:

```py
Photos.objects.select_related("ship", "ship__address")
```

Or you can use `prefetch_related()` to fetch all related objects in one query:

```py
Ship.objects.prefetch_related("photoship").select_related("address")
```

Please refer to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for details on how prefetch works. There are many options and some caveats.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Here the following:
1. The first approach had naturally been tried by me but the result was as predicted, it would fetch me the values of photos and ship but not those of address.
2. The prefetch_related only retrieves data from its own very table, that is, photos, so it produces nothing of value.
3. We want to have the data of the three tables, so that we can send them to the html template.,
4. My opinion is that both the class-based views as well as the ORM are rubbish, only valid for very simple scenarios.

Comment: I updated the queries to also include address to make it hopefully more clear to you how the ORM works. Also keep in mind that you can always use raw SQL in Django if you have a special case that is not covered by the ORM (but this is not one of those in my opinion).

Comment: If you want to further discuss the pro and cons of Django ORM I would recommend to head over to the Django subreddit. Stack Overflow is not a place for opinions.https://www.reddit.com/r/django/

Comment: I will try that one as soon as I can write on my computer.,. I have read all the documentation on the matter at django project and they limit themselves to very simple scenarios. What you have written is more advanced and shophisticated that I would have never in a lifetime figured out, because I had no base to get to that, where?
I will try those queries tonight. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: worked.  I specify that only one of the queries worked, this one:
Photos.objects.select_related("ship", "ship__address")
the other one again, just gave me ship and addres but not photos.
I must say that I confirm what I say, the documentation at django project only refers to simple cases, would have never figured it out by myself. Thank you. Regards